# Using Javascript, can I "read" a h2 class on a page and retrieve and display data related to that value

Tags: javascript, php, html

*not looking for code to be provided, just want to know if its possible.

For example. I have an h2 class named "stock-number" and its value is #NC123456. Can javascript read each instance of that class, fetch data from another database using that value, and display the results in another class.

Real world example would be if I sold TVs. The TV has an msrp and inventory is retrieved from one database. However, we can set a sale price. and the discounts and rebates are from another database, sorted by that tvs stock number.

Can I read that stock number, pull the pricing break down from the other database, and display in back into the page underneath the sale price in its own div so customers understand their savings?

Comment: how does an H2 have a class name with a value? can we see the mark up?

Comment: ie. <h2 class="Price">#Value</h2>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can.

In order to do the database lookup, receive the returned data, and update the DOM with new data, you also need to use AJAX.

[Basic ajax tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/)

You might also want to [compare jQuery code](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_intro.asp) to the above pure javascript code -- most folks find jQuery a lot faster/easier (especially with AJAX).

jQuery is a library that runs on top of javascript and all that is required in order to use it is to include the library somewhere on the page:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Awesome, I figured those would be involved, but I am by no means a javascript developer so I wanted to make sure that it was possible.

Comment: There are some great (free) video micro courses on jQuery over at [TheNewBoston](https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=32) and some more excellent stuff (same teacher) at [CodeCourse.com](http://codecourse.com) *This is where I learned all my jQuery -- don't believe those who say you must learn pure javascript first. I didn't, and was productive within a few hours/days as opposed to weeks.*

Comment: Thanks good to hear Gib, I'm going back to school this fall so im sure that will lend some time to check it out.